# OpenCV window not working on mac

Tags: python, macos, opencv, opencv3.0, python-3.6

So here is my code:

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('new.bmp')
cv2.imshow('FRAME', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

From what I have gathered on the internet, this is supposed to display the image 'new.bmp' in a window called'FRAME'. But all that happens is
[**this!**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsA6a.png). Can anyone help me?

Comment: does it load the image? the code seems to be ok, but it could be that it could not find the image or load it correctly...

Comment: @api55 It doesn't show any errors. How can I confirm if the image is loaded? I even tried loading the image though PIL then dumping its numpy array. I am quite familiar with PIL and can confirm the image was loaded.

Comment: Try grabbing a random JPG, GIF, or PNG from somewhere on the Web, and loading that instead to rule out any Microsoft madness in BMP files.

Comment: Nope. Not working. Exactly the same as before.

Comment: Which python are you using and how did you install it? Which OpenCV are you using and how did you install it?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I have python 3.6.0, homebrewed.

Opencv 3.2, I installed it with the help of a tutorial from pyimagesearch.com.
However I didn't install it in a virtual environment

Comment: I am no expert on Python (or OpenCV) but when I installed `Python3` via `homebrew`, I noticed that gave me a new binary called `/usr/local/bin/pip3` and it seems that if I use that (rather than plain `pip`) the packages I install are available in the `Python3` which I `homebrewed` whereas I believe anything I install with plain `pip` becomes associated with the Apple-supplied Python 2.x.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I didn't have to use pip to install opencv.

Comment: If you want to confirm if the image has been loaded, just check the dimensions of img by doing `height, width, channels = img.shape `

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki I can confirm the image has loaded. I am reinstalling opencv on a shitty internet connection, will report tommorow probably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a silly installation problem.

I wholeheartedly apologize.

Comment: Hi Sir, i'm facing the exact problem followed the same guide, it might also be a stupid mistake i made, i wonder where did your installation went wrong?, Sincerely [And here is a link to my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44603844/opencv-python-cv2-imshow-only-showing-top-bar-on-mac?noredirect=1#comment76219974_44603844]

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is facing this issue - please install *pycharm* and run your code there it will automatically open the webcam for you! hope this helps