# OpenCV-python: cv2.imshow() only showing top bar on mac

Tags: python, macos, opencv

So i setup OpenCV and python3 on my mac using the guide here:
http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/12/05/macos-install-opencv-3-and-python-3-5/#comment-427533

In one of his guide, he has an example code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import argparse
import cv2

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required = True, help = "From Terminal")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())


image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
cv2.imwrite("./Output/image1.jpg", image)
cv2.imshow("Test_imShow", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

After i execute it in terminal with

```
python read_n_write.py --image ./Resource/Me.jpg
```

while the imwrite function successfully creates a duplicate of the read image, imshow failed to display it in the window. There's no background, just a floating top window bar. 
[image]

I'm really confused here, after a bit of google, i've tried the suggested solution

```
cv2.startWindowThread()
cv2.namedWindow("test")
```

Both won't work, any suggestions would be appreciated, thank you.

---

**Edit 1:**
Big thanks to api55.  I used matplotlib

```
plt.imshow(canvas, interpolation='nearest')
plt.show()
```

And it totally worked, still have no idea why cv2.imshow isn't working. So i will leave this question open.

Comment: If you've installed Python 3 then why are you using `from __future__ import print_function`? This is for the newest versions of Python 2 to use the `print()` function from Python 3. Additionally, check `which python` to see what version of Python terminal is executing.

Comment: If you installed `python3`, shouldn't you invoke `python3 read_n_write.py --image ./Resource/Me.jpg`? What does `python -V` give you and `python3 -V`?

Comment: @MarkSetchell, i tried python3 read_n_write...., same result.  python -V and python3 -V both give me python 3.6.1

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds, in the book it mentioned: "Throughout this book you’ll see us importing the print_ function from the __future__ package. We’ll be using the actual print() function rather than the print statement so that our code will work with both Python 2.7 and Python 3". And by checking python verions, it is python 3.6.1

Comment: Your screenshot looks kind of weird, the new window should not be call Image, but Test_imShow as in your code. If it is called Image, something is completely wrong :/ either the code is not the one shown here or the opencv has this by default and is somehow skipping the instructions. You can try plotting it [with matplotlib](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html), to check if indeed the problem is openCV imshow function.

Comment: @api55, thank you i just tested with matplotlib code: plt.imshow(canvas, interpolation='nearest') ||| plt.show() It worked

Comment: good, so this tells you that something with the imshow function is not working good. However your code is quite simple, so I am out of ideas of why it may not work. Perhaps a version problem, or if you got them from source, perhaps there is a bug?

Comment: @api55 yes, I agree, I posted this question to the author of the guide I mentioned, hoping he might find a solution.

Comment: You may also try the github issues section, since this may be a bug (maybe it is even reported already)

Comment: Curious, does it fail if you make the argument positional instead of optional? I.e. `ap.add_argument('image', help='From Terminal')` and then calling with `python read_n_write.py ./Resource/Me.jpg`?

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds . I tried. It says [[[ usage: load_display_save.py [-h] image
load_display_save.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --image ]]]

Comment: I ran into a similar issue a while ago and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44553641/4962554) was my solution